# Preload="none" does not work for ie8

Tags: jquery, css, video, internet-explorer-8

I embedded a video on my website which was working fine but the problem started when i inserted preload="none"

```
<video width="314" height="182" controls="controls" preload="none" poster="http://www.tsbagroup.com/ShopCentral/Media/CorpGiftMenu/corpGiftsVideo.jpg">
<source src="http://www.tsbagroup.com/ShopCentral/Media/CorpGiftMenu/corpGiftsVideo.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="http://www.tsbagroup.com/ShopCentral/Media/CorpGiftMenu/corpGiftsVideo.webm" type="video/webm" />
<source src="http://www.tsbagroup.com/ShopCentral/Media/CorpGiftMenu/corpGiftsVideo.ogv" type="video/ogg" /> 
</video>
```

Then the video dissapeared when i browse the my website on IE8. is there any other tool i can use for IE8 besides flash player?

Comment: I'm wondering why the video appeared in the first place. IE8 doesn't support `<video>`. Which Flash fallback player do you use?

Comment: I wanted to use object but decided to remove it since it was working with <video>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Preload=“none” propriety is not supported, as seen at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_preload.asp). For fallback you need to use some js... good plugin is http://www.videojs.com/! Or try this generator: http://v4e.thewikies.com/
I hope it helps!

Comment: I understand that. what is an alternative besides flash

Comment: I edited the answer... You can use http://www.videojs.com/docs/setup/ for make some fallback and also personalize the player ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Internet Explorer 8 does not support `<video>`](http://caniuse.com/video) *at all*, let alone the `preload` attribute.

Have a look at using [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/). It's a a script which uses HTML5 `<video>` if support is available, falling back to Flash or Silverlight players if it's not. It should work fine with the HTML code you've posted above.